# Django: How to avoid reassigning ForeignKey on every save?

Tags: django, django-database

I want to save the `A` object and `B` object. `A` has a foreignkey to `B`. `B` has a OneToOneField to `A`. Is there a way I can get around having to reassign the variables between each save? or perhaps there's a better way to do it?

```
# The models a and b were created earlier in code
# a.b = b  Was already set earlier in code
# b.a = a  Was already set earlier in code
with transaction.commit_on_success():
    a.save() # pk created for a
    b.a = a  # attach a.pk to b
    b.save() # pk created for b
    a.b = b  # attach b.pk to a
    a.save() # re-save a to database
```

Answer (score 1):

"A has a foreignkey to B. B has a OneToOneField to A."  I don't think this is the way to set up your relationships.  You can just set B as a ForeignKey of A and then you can access A from B using B.a_set.all().

To paraphrase from [here](http://www.djangobook.com/en/2.0/chapter10.html), with the following model definitions, Book is one-to-many (ForeignKey) with Publisher and many-to-many with Author. (The ~~~~ just means other stuff not related to the relationships between the models)

```
class Publisher(~~~~):
    ~~~~

class Author(~~~~):
    ~~~~

class Book(~~~~):
    publisher = models.ForeignKey(Publisher)
    authors = models.ManyToManyField(Author)
```

Then you can access publisher and author from a given book like so:

```
b = Book.objects.get(id=50)
publisher1 = b.publisher # publisher object for a given book
author_set = b.authors.all() # query set of authors for a given book
```

and you can do the reverse relationship (which isn't explicitly defined in the models above).

```
p = Publisher.objects.get(name='Apress Publishing')
p.book_set.all() # query set of books for a given publisher
publisher1.book_set.all() # set of books for the publisher from above.
a = Author.objects.get(name="JK Rowling")
a.book_set.all() # query set of books for a given author
```

Any time you update an object field you need to call `save()` to save it in the database, but you shouldn't need to reassign ForeignKey or any other field before doing so.  If that wasn't working for you, maybe it was because of the funky relationship between the models.  I'm not 100% sure, but I think the only time an object gets a (new) primary key is the first time it's saved to the database, and then that's its first pk.

Comment: You're correct that the pk is only created the first time the model is saved (unfortunately that doesn't mean any less coding is needed  :(  ). The reason I have a OneToOneField is to easily keep track of the last created A model. If I don't have that OneToOneField, then I have to use a reverse access from B, and this requires a database search everytime. Wasted calculations and database accesses. `b.a.order_by('created')[-1]`